# Gitlab CI returns error - no such host error

Tags: docker, continuous-integration, gitlab

My gitlab-ci runs only after several attempts of retries. It returns the following error almost all the time -

> Successfully installed PyYAML-3.13 awscli-1.16.133 botocore-1.12.123 colorama-0.3.9 docutils-0.14 futures-3.2.0 jmespath-0.9.4 pyasn1-0.4.5 python-dateutil-2.8.0 rsa-3.4.2 s3transfer-0.2.0 six-1.12.0 urllib3-1.24.1
>
> You are using pip version 10.0.1, however version 19.0.3 is available.
>
> You should consider upgrading via the 'pip install --upgrade pip' command.
>
> $ $(aws ecr get-login --no-include-email --region us-east-1)
>
> WARNING! Using --password via the CLI is insecure. Use --password-stdin.
>
> error during connect: Post http://docker:2375/v1.39/auth: dial tcp: lookup docker on [ip here]:53: no such host
>
> ERROR: Job failed: command terminated with exit code 1

Sometimes I ran into this error after I run the **docker build** command:

> time="2019-03-28T18:20:24Z" level=error msg="failed to dial gRPC: cannot connect to the Docker daemon. Is 'docker daemon' running on this host?: dial tcp: lookup docker on 10.19.240.10:53: no such host"
>   context canceled

However, after a couple of retries(a lot), the CI runs successfully and builds the docker image etc.

This is my yaml file(involving where it stops):

```
image: docker:stable
variables:
  DOCKER_HOST: tcp://docker:2375/
  DOCKER_DRIVER: overlay2

services:
  - docker:dind

before_script:
  - apk add --no-cache curl jq python py-pip sed git curl-dev bash git
  - pip install awscli

stages:
  - build
  - deploy_staging
  - deploy_production
```

I searched for some possible solutions but have not had luck yet.
Thanks

Answer (score 3):

In case anyone gets this issue where your runners just keep failing all of a sudden,
simply clearing the cache in the pipeline menu will resolve this.

You need to be a maintainer of the project to be able to do this.

Comment: Thanks! This is a concrete solution that actually worked for me. I had seen many suggestions for workarounds, but none really addressed the cause of the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Remove below variable from Dockerfile

`DOCKER_HOST: tcp://docker:2375/`

and

Edit `config.toml`, default file location `/etc/gitlab-runner/config.toml` and modify the replace the below line on existing entry of volume

`volumes = ["/var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock", "/cache"]`

Answer (score 0):

Another reason this could be happening is because the DinD container is not allowed to run in privileged (root) mode. This means it cannot start the docker-in-docker container causing docker commands to fail. More on this at https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/executors/docker.html#the-privileged-mode